# Docker push to amazon ECR succeeds but doesn't show up in web UI

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, aws-ecs

I have a jenkinsfile with the following push to docker

```
          def image = docker.build("namespace/myapp:${env.DOCKER_TAG}", ".")
          docker.withRegistry('https://12345566622.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'ecr:us-east-1: ecr_beanstalk'){
              image.push()
          }
```

It pushes properly, with a few layers "already pushed", and finishes with the following log output:

```
2fa2cf8e1a50: Layer already exists
c384087b50dc: Pushed
3b7571ef2a62: Pushed
0764508fafe4: Pushed
<tag>: digest: 
sha256:f0873f95a4427a52d2fcd2cbab85abb340daf600f62cfb7716ff9781e69c0df9 
size: 4725
```

But when I go to amazon ecr, there has not been anything pushed. I am clueless as to what could be the problem. Any help would be much appreciated. How can I go about debugging this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the push was succeeding but the web UI wasn't displaying the correct results when I searched for the tag.